# Почему Intellij IDEA не находит ConnectionManager?

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]`intellij idea` не предлагает мне достать из пакета `Util > ConnectionManager,` чтобы потом преобразовать в

```
Connection connection = ConnectionManager.get()
```

что я делаю не так?

[image: ConnectionManager]

Comment: Либо импортируйте вручную: `import project.site.util.ConnectionManager`, либо нажмите `Alt + Enter` и идея должна предложить Вам варианты для импорта.

Comment: тоже самое вчера делал и всегда было красным... спасибо видимо надо идею рестарнуть